# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T^*T$

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

I am working on the following problem:

> Define a bounded linear operator $T$ on $L^2[0,1]$ as $$Tf(x)=\int_x^1 f(t)dt, \; f \in L^2[0,1], \; x \in [0,1].$$ Find the range of $T^*+T$ and the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T^*T$.

I started by noticing that
$$
T^*g(x)= \int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt.
$$

So I got $$(T^*+T)f=\int_0^1f(t)dt.$$ At this point, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequelity I have $$(T^*+T)f \leq \|f\|_2,$$ and so I want to say that $\text{range}(T^*+T)=\{c \in \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } c=\|f\|_2 \text{ for some } f \in L^2[0,1] \}$.

Finally, I think $T^*T$ has no eigenvalues, since neither $T$ nor $T^*$ have some. Am I correct? Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** as Aaron pointed out, we have $(T^*T)^*=T^*T^{**}=T^*T$. So the operator is self-adjoint and therefore it will have non-negative eigenvalues.

Comment: It should be $(Tf)'=-f$, as $x$ is the lower limit of the integral.

Comment: right thanks, I'll change that

Comment: In the finite dimensional case, even if $A$ has no real eigenvalues, $A^*A$ will.  I would not assume as you have.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron! I modified my question. Now I'm trying to prove that $TT^*$ is compact, because then the Spectral Theorem would apply and I could say that real eigenvalues exist. Having that, then I coul take an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $TT^*$ and say $TT^*f= \lambda f \Rightarrow T^*(TT^*)f=\lambda T^*f \Rightarrow (T^*T)(T^*f)=\lambda (T^*f)$, and so $T^*T$ has eigenvalues $\lambda$ with eigenvectors $T^*f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found, $T+T^*$ is a rank-one operator, and its range are the constant functions.

As $T$ is compact, so is $T^*T$. So its spectrum will consist of zero and positive eigenvalues.

If $\lambda>0$ and $T^*Tf=\lambda f$, we have
$$\tag1
\lambda f=\int_0^x\int_t^1f(s)\,ds\,dt.
$$
Since $f$ is in $L^2$, it is also in $L^1$ (use Cauchy-Schwarz) and so $Tf$ is continuous. It follows that $\lambda f$ is differentiable, and going back and forth we get that $f$ is C$^\infty$. Differentiating $(1)$ we obtain
$$\tag2
\lambda f'=\int_x^1f(s)\,ds,
$$
and differentiating once more
$$\tag3
\lambda f''=-f.
$$
The solutions to $(3)$ are of the form
$$
f(t)=\alpha\,\cos\frac t{\sqrt\lambda}+\beta\,\sin\frac t{\sqrt\lambda}.
$$
From $(1)$ we have the initial condition $f(0)=0$, which gives $\alpha=0$. And from $(2)$ we have $f'(1)=0$, which gives
$$
0=\beta\,\cos\frac1{\sqrt\lambda}.
$$
As the sine is zero on $\frac\pi2+k\pi$, $k\in\mathbb Z$, we get
$$
\lambda_k=\frac4{(2k+1)^2\pi^2},\qquad k\in\mathbb N,
$$
with eigenvectors
$$
f_k(t)=\sin 2k\pi t.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I think there is a little mistake: we have $f'(1)=0 \Rightarrow \beta \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \right) =0$, and so $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}= \frac{2k+1}{2}\pi$, which gives $\lambda= \frac{4}{\pi^2(2k+1)^2}$. Am I right?

Comment: Indeed! Edited.